# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'Date'. in updae query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
update Tbl_IncomingCheck 
     set  bank_name = 'MCB' Date = 'Wednesday, October 17, 2018' Check_No = '34534' Payee = 'fsdfsa' Amount = '43543' Remarks = 'sdfdsf' 
where Incoming_Check_Id = '4'
```

Comment: You need a `,` between the field = value tokens

Comment: I don't think this topic required quite the volume of downvotes it's received. it appears the the user is simply unfamiliar/inexperienced with the syntax. :[UPDATE (SQL SERVER)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: On a completely different note: `Date = 'Wednesday, October 17, 2018'` is completely wrong. This **strongly implies** you're storing your dates as a `varchar`. Store your data in a datatype appropriate for what they are. **Store a Date as a `date`** (you also have `Check_No = '34534'`, I really hope you aren't storing numbers as a `varchar` too). `varchar` **is not** a "one size fits all" datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states, you have syntax errors in your query. Your key value pairs must be separated by commas, giving you the following:

```
UPDATE Tbl_IncomingCheck 
SET  bank_name = 'MCB',
     Date = 'Wednesday, October 17, 2018',
     Check_No = '34534',
     Payee = 'fsdfsa',
     Amount = '43543',
     Remarks = 'sdfdsf' 
WHERE Incoming_Check_Id = '4'
```